# Production servers can suddenly not access the internet anymore

Tags: networking, switch, internet, scientific-linux, eth0

**Problem**

All Production Servers were suddenly not able to access the internet anymore, while four other Servers connected to the same VLAN and same eth0 settings can.

[image]

**Figure 1:** `System 1` represents the four systems which are able to access the internet, while `System 2` indicates the ones which suddenly cannot since today afternoon.

**Analysis**

- System 1 can access System 2 and vice versa
- `Default Gateway` (10.10.10.1) can be pinged from System 1 and System 2 as well
- System 1 can access the
  internet
- System 2 cannot access the internet
- Ifconfig's `eth0` configuration identical between all Production Servers
- Internal DNS server is identical to other
  systems which can access the internet
- The IP's and names located in `/etc/resolve.conf` can be accessed
- The internet can be accessed from the Switch
- Configuration of all 8 Switchports on Cisco IOS is identical
- Tracepath from System 2 to
  8.8.8.8 (DNS Google), google IP or google.com hangs at the `Default Gateway`
- The systems which cannot access the system seems to have an `em1` adapter instead of `eth0`
- `sudo arping -I eth0 ping.tweakers.net` works on all 8 systems
- One of the systems which cannot access the internet show an output if `sudo iptables-save` has been executed
- Output `route -n` is identical between all the systems

*Tracepath*

```
[username@hostname ~]$ tracepath google.com
 1:  10.10.10.10 (10.10.10.10)                                  0.222ms pmtu 1500
 1:  10.10.10.1 (10.10.10.1)                                    0.662ms
 1:  10.10.10.1 (10.10.10.1)                                    0.601ms
 2:  no reply
```

*ARP*

**System1:** `? (10.10.10.1) at AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF [ether] on em1`

**System2:** `? (10.10.10.1) at AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF [ether] on eth0`

*Output iptables-save on one of the systems which cannot access the internet*

```
# Generated by iptables-save vX on Fri Aug  1 10:00:01 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [X:Y]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [X:Y]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Aug  1 10:00:01 2014
```

*route -n*

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.10.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
X.Y.0.0         0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     Z      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         10.10.10.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

It is unclear why the internet cannot be accessed anymore from the four production servers. As these are running in Production, a restart of the network should be prevented. Which further tests could be done to investigate the issue?

Comment: The actual `tracepath` output may provide a hint. Also check the ARP cache on each system to see if they have the same MAC for the gateway. You can use `arp -n` to see the ARP cache.

Comment: @kasperd `Tracepath` output has been added. I will check the `ARP` of each system at my work tomorrow. I have executed `arp -n` on a local test system and the MAC address of the adapters differ compared to `ifconfig`, while the internet can be accessed. Could you explain why there is a discrepancy and why the internet can be accessed and what could be concluded by investigating the output of `arp -n`

Comment: The ARP cache doesn't contain the MAC address of the host itself, it contains the MAC addresses of the hosts it is communicating with. The `tracepath` output shows the packets are making it to the gateway and back, so there is nothing suggesting it would be an ARP related problem. Rather the root cause is likely to be found on the gateway. Maybe a misconfigured NAT.

Comment: @kasperd Executing `arp -n` on a VM showed a MAC address which is identical to my host. This is correct as the VM communicates via the Host to the internet. Thank you for the explanation. I will search commands to check the NAT table now.

Comment: @kasperd Could you indicate whether [these commands](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-iptables-show-nat-rules/) are useful to investigate the NAT?

Comment: If the NAT is running on Linux, then those commands should work. However I prefer looking at the rules in the format output by `iptables-save`, as that provides the complete rule set with no details missing.

Comment: @kasperd The systems which cannot access the internet seems to have `em1` instead of `eth0` adapter (found after executing `arp -a`)

Comment: Seems Fedora switched to a different naming scheme for network interfaces. But there is nothing suggesting that would be causing connectivity problems.

Comment: `sudo arping -I em1 <IP>` works from the systems which cannot ping the internet

Comment: Yes, the `tracepath` output already established, that there is no connectivity problem between the host and gateway. Symptoms suggest the problem is a misconfiguration on the NAT.

Comment: `sudo iptables-save` shows an output on one of the four systems which cannot access the internet. I will check the NAT on the switch as well.